# How to get the features in the kind of vector layer which is created by using protocol?

Tags: openlayers

I am learning OpenLayers now. I found a strange thing about the vector layer when I using protocol to create it, for example:

```
 var scheldtoutflow = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("scheldtoutflow", {
     projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
     protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
               url: "data/scheldtoutflow",
               format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            }),
               visibility: false
          });
```

when I debug this code I found that the features list for this layer is empty. Only if I register some events to the layer, e.g. select feature and so on, the feature list can become correct.

Does anyone know why it is like this? Thank you very much.

Cheers,
Xuan

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this issue could be very similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171238/openlayers-features-array-is-empty).  I think you are trying to test the features list inline while the call to populate the features is going to call an HTTP request asynchronously.  The features will be empty as you will be interrogating them before the HTTP request has returned.  To do this correctly you need to add a handler to the [layer loadend event](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.events) to interogate the features