# Get parameter from geoJson

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

Hello I am using the following code to load geoJson file from my java server application. It works withoout problem and I can display the geojson as vector layer in openlayers. But on the server side I am also saving some parameters to the geoJson file that I want to read later on the client javaScript side (such as total length of the path and total time of the path.) I do not know how to access them.

This is what I have, and what works:

```
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Path", {
                style: style,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                projection: geographic,
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "webresources/getJosmAspects?startLon=" + document.getElementById('startLon').value +
                            "&startLat=" + document.getElementById('startLat').value +
                            "&endLon=" + document.getElementById('endLon').value +
                            "&endLat=" + document.getElementById('endLat').value +
                            "&avgSpeed=" + document.getElementById('avgSpeed').value +
                            "&speedWeight=" + document.getElementById('speedInput').value +
                            "&comfortWeight=" + document.getElementById('comfortInput').value +
                            "&quietnessWeight=" + document.getElementById('quietInput').value +
                            "&avgSpeedWeight=" + document.getElementById('shortestInput').value,
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                })
            });
```

I would like to get some parameters from the response without calling it once again.
geojson from server looks like

```
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[14.420414,50.07352]......,[14.38296,50.077154],[14.382867,50.077228]]},"properties":{"total_length":3603.656606483625,"total_time":782.4648477846279,"total_elevationGain":130.9226633310318,"total_elevationDrop":-48.82620286941528}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was, I was not able to read the features of the layer because it was no fully loaded yet (asynchronous call). It can be solved by adding event listener on "loadend" event. To this is working:

```
layer.events.register("loadend", layer, function() {
                window.alert(layer.features[layer.features.length - 1].attributes.total_time);
            });
```

It is discussed here: [How to get the features in the kind of vector layer which is created by using protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993025/how-to-get-the-features-in-the-kind-of-vector-layer-which-is-created-by-using-pr)